# cant create nestjs project i have a error and cant find it on google

Tags: nestjs

```
nest new my project
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/ast.js:86
    #fillNegs(){
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

I am new in NestJS i am trying to install it and create a project fro  offical documentation, can you pls help me to fix this problem

Comment: Node version? `@nestjs/cli` version? Any other relevant information you can provide?

Comment: node --version
v12.22.9
npm --version
8.5.1

Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: try change your node version to 14. Because some code of `minimatch` using version 14 operator. For example: `?.`

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. It has something to do with @nestjs/cli. Downgrading it to the latest v8 version worked for me. All other NestJS packages are still on the latest v9.

```
npm install --save-dev @nestjs/cli@^8.2.8
```